# How can I make an image move a certain distance every half second?

Tags: javascript

I'm making a web page that has two cars racing against each other. When the stop light image is clicked it starts the race. Two random numbers are created and whichever one is bigger will make one of the cars move 5px. But when I start the race, both cars move to the end of the screen at the exact same time when they should just be moving 50px every half second until they cross the finish.

Edit: I changed up things a litte bit. Only made one random number variable and made it so if one of the images reaches 1000px, it will stop. But they keep going. Why is that? For now I have just made it when it reaches 1000px it displays an alert but it will display the image of the winner which is currently set to display: none.

I would reference your examples but this is a homework assignment and I can only use stuff I have learned (I know that's impossible for you guys to know what I have learned.)

```
<script>
    var player1 = 0;
    var player2 = 0;
    function setTimer() {
        document.getElementById("race").src = "greenlight.png";
        var i = setInterval(startRace, 200);

    }
    var length = 50;

    function startRace() {


        var num1 = Math.floor(Math.random()*2);

            if (num1 == 0) {

                var move1 = player1 + length;
                player1 = player1 + 50;
                document.getElementById("car1").style.left = move1 + "px";


            }
            else if (num1 == 1) {

                var move2 = player2 + length;
                player2+=50;
                document.getElementById("car2").style.left = move2 + "px";

            }
        }

            if (player1 == 1000)
            {
                alert("Player 1 wins");
                clearInterval(i);
            }
            else if (player2 == 1000)
            {
                alert("Player 2 wins");
                clearInterval(i);
            }

    }




</script>
```

Comment: Please do not edit your question such that it invalidates existing answers. Instead, create a new question.

Answer (score 0):

What happens is that each loop of the while is so fast the eye can not see, so you only see it as if it would go all the way to the end.

What you might try to do is do if with a setTimer to control each loop better, like this:

```js
var i = 5;                     

function moveCar () {           
  setTimeout(function () {    
     
    //Your code
 var num1 = Math.floor(Math.random()*2);
    var num2 = Math.floor(Math.random()*2);

    if (num1 > num2) {
        var increment = i + 'px';            
        document.getElementById("car1").style.left = increment;
    }
    else if (num2 > num1) {
        var increment = i + 'px';
        document.getElementById("car2").style.left = increment;
    }
    else {
        var increment = i + 'px';
        document.getElementById("car1").style.left = increment;
        document.getElementById("car2").style.left = increment;
    }

 i = i + 5;
   //Your code

 if (i < $(window).width() - 120) {     
  // width() returns the screen width
  // - 120 because of the size of the box when reaching the end, not necessarilly your case
  moveCar();   //Keep calling the function              
 }
  }, 50);     //Time for each moveCar() loop executed
}

$('#start').click(function(){
 moveCar(); 
});
```

```css
.box{
 background-color: #dddddd;
 height: 120px;
 width: 120px;
 position: absolute; 
 font-family: Helvetica;
}

#car1{
 top: 20px;
 left: 0px;
}

#car2{
 top: 160px;
 left: 0px;
}

#start{
 top: 360px;
 left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>  
<span class="box" id="car1">car 1</span>
<span class="box" id="car2">car 2</span>        
<div class="box" id="start">START</div>
```

Hope this help you out in winning that race.

Leo.

Comment: I have added the loop that starts the function over. That seemed to do the trick to make the cars move. Now I just need to know how I can get them to stop when they reach the end of my screen at around 1700px..

Comment: You could use the $(window).width() which returns the width of the screen at the moment, also if you do that, you might want to reduce the width from the cars object, I already updated it in my answer, let me know if it helps.

Comment: I'm using images as the cars, I've made some changes so that the cars stop when they reach 1000px with a loop but the cars continue to move and never stop.

Comment: Also, I'm kind of limited on what code I can use, this is an assignment and can only use stuff I have learned thus far :/

Answer (score 0):

You may try this skeleton and reuse it.

```js
var cars = document.getElementsByClassName('car');
var thread_id;
var run_way = document.getElementById('view_port');

document.getElementById('start_btn').onclick = function() {
  if (thread_id) {
    clearInterval(thread_id);
  }

  var car_edge;
  var quit_race = false;
  var max_speed = 5;
  var total_cars = cars.length;
  while (total_cars--)
    cars[total_cars].style.left = "0px";

  thread_id = setInterval(function() {
    var finish_line = run_way.offsetWidth;
    var move_by;
    total_cars = cars.length;
    while (total_cars--) {
      if (quit_race) {
        return;
      }
      move_by = Math.floor(Math.random() * max_speed);
      car_edge = parseInt(cars[total_cars].offsetLeft) + cars[total_cars].width;
      if ((car_edge + move_by) < finish_line) {
        cars[total_cars].style.left = (car_edge + move_by) + 'px';
      } else {
        quit_race = true;
        clearInterval(thread_id);
      }
    }
    if (quit_race) {
      alert('Race over !');
    }
  }, 500);
};
```

```css
.car {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
}
#car_1 {
  top: 40px;
}
#car_2 {
  top: 65px;
}
#view_port {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Start" id='start_btn' />
<br/>
<div id="view_port">
  <img src="http://plainicon.com/dl.php?pid=40556&tem=24px&con=download-icon" id='car_1' class='car' />
  <img src="http://plainicon.com/dl.php?pid=40556&tem=24px&con=download-icon" id='car_2' class='car' />
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is a homework assignment and I can only use stuff I have learned before. I have made some different changes to my code based on some I've seen but the images still don't stop.